# In Odoo, what would happen if the method of computed field is assigning a value to other fields?

Tags: orm, odoo, computed-field

Let say we have a model with three fields with the following definition:

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    _name = 'my.model'
    field_a = fields.Char('Field A')
    field_b = fields.Char('Field B')
    field_c = fields.Char('Field C', compute='compute_field_c', store=True)

    @api.depends('field_b')
    def compute_field_c(self):
        for rec in self:
             rec.field_c = (rec.field_b or '') + ' something else'
             re.field_a = 'test to see if this works properly'
```

`field_c` is computed from `field_b` and `field_a` is just a normal char field. I wonder what would happen if inside the compute method we also assign a value to `field_a`. I know it is not a good practice but I recently maintain some modules with this kind of architecture, the program seems to work normally but I wonder if there will some issues in a long run.

Comment: Very interesting question. Would be nice if a very deep odoo framework insider could answer it. In my experience, this use does not cause any problems. It is much worse not to fill `depends` correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the obvious typo

```
re.field_a
```

I don't see any other problems with it.

Comment: thanks, it just feels weird to assign a value to a field by a compute method other than the computed fields themselves..